# Why isn't this criterion for determining irreducibilty working?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

I have learned this criterion for irreducibility of polynomials:

> Let $R$ be an integral domain, let $I$ be a proper ideal of $R$, and let $p(x)$ be a non-constant monic polynomial in $R[x]$. If the image of $p(x)$ is irreducible in $(R/ I)[x]$ under the natural homomorphism, then $p(x)$ is irreducible in $R[x]$.

Now the polynomial $xy+x+y+1 = (x+1)(y+1)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x, y] = (\mathbb{Z}[y])[x]$. Take $R = \mathbb{Z}[y]$ and $I = (y)$. Then the image of $xy+x+y+1$ in $(\mathbb{Z}[y]/(y))[x]$ is $x+1$, which is irreducible because $\mathbb{Z}[y]/(y) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Why does this criterion seem to not work in this situation?

**Edit: Proof of the criterion**

We prove the contrapositive. Suppose $p(x)$ is reducible, $p(x) = a(x)b(x)$. Since $p(x)$ is monic, $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are non-constant and monic. Thus when you reduce the coefficients $\pmod I$ you get a factorization in $(R/I)[x]$.

Comment: Where did you find that criterion?

Comment: @KennyLau I forgot to add that $p(x)$ is non-constant and monic. My friend told me this criterion, and the contrapositive has an easy proof: Suppose is reducible, $p(x) = a(x)b(x)$. Since $p(x)$ is monic, $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are non-constant and monic. Thus when you reduce the coefficients $\pmod I$ you get a factorization in $(R/I)[x]$.

Comment: Add that to the question.

Comment: @KennyLau Done ${}$

Comment: @GalPorat $x+1$ and $y+1$ are non-units, so that is a perfectly valid proof that the polynomial is reducible.

Comment: Is $xy+x+y+1$ really monic in $(\mathbb{Z}[y])[x]$ ?

Comment: @KennyLau yes sorry, I thought the definition of reducible here only refers to a product of two polynomials of nonzero degree, since the criterion was written differently before the OP edited the question. I deleted my comment after reading the OP's comment which appeared right after my post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$xy + x + y + 1 \in (\Bbb Z[y])[x]$ is not monic, for its leading coefficient is $y+1$.

Comment: Ohhhhh thanks! ${}$